# Dissolve output not dissolved in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

Even though polygons of an input feature have the same attributes/dissolve fields, the output does look like in the picture below.

[image: Dissolve problem]

Does anybody know what the problem is?

---

This problem occurs only in ModelBuilder. When I use the same data and same default parameters and do not calculate it in ModelBuilder, it works normally.

---

The original input feature looks like in the picture below. So the "cross division" in the picture one does not come from the original dataset but it is created by the Dissolve tool.

[image: Input dataset]

---

I tried to delete whitespaces - still the same problem.

There are no gaps between common edges.

I tried to run dissolve multiple times in ModelBuilder - still the same problem.

When I try it normally (without ModelBuilder, the same parameters), it works normally.

Any other ideas?

Since I work with many input features, I need to work with ModelBuilder.

---

This is what the model looks like. (Model works fine till the last part - dissolve. Goal is to generate polygons that represent areas of municipalites with the same closest facilities - in my case central cities with specific types of public institutions, also one central city can have more than one facilities)

[image: Model]

Comment: You may have a gap between the common edges.

Comment: I’ve had this happen on particularly large datasets. If you try running dissolve again on this dataset, it should resolve it. I believe it’s an internal tiling that isn’t properly resolved within the Geoprocessing tool.

Comment: Please update your post to include any non-default parameter values that you used in the Dissolve tool.

Comment: Yep, name_fac is a string field. I tried .strip() to delete whitespaces but it hasnt solved the "dissolve problem"...

Comment: It is frequently the case with large sets.

Comment: What does ModelBuilder have to do with working with a large dataset?  What does your model that does no more than the tool dialog look like?

Comment: I mean I need to iterate through aprox. 60 input features...

Comment: Ok, I hope it will help.